# init.d how to start a service in init.d when networking fully works?

Tags: linux, services

I have a python script which exposes a RESTful service (using flask framework). What I would like to do with this service is that it clones the newest version of the python script, and then it starts main.py.

It is clear to me that it might be started at init level 3, how ever I am not sure how exactly the init info has to be configured and also I am not sure if it's okay to update the crontab with

```
sudo update-rc.d myservice enable 3
```

what's really in myservice script is something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -fR /home/pi/myservicedir
git clone https://repo/code.git /home/pi/myservicedir
cd /home/pi/myservicedir
python main.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is not a proper `init.d` script.  There may be a template file in `/etc/init.d` that you can use to create your start script.  Otherwise, look at some of the other scripts in `/etc/init.d` to find the pattern used by your distribution.

Alternatively, `rc.local` is usually run very late in the boot cycle.  This would be an appropriate place to put your startup code.  Check the value of `$1` is `start` before running your code.

The servers are started in the order listed in `/etc/rc3.d`.  Kill scripts starting `K` are run first in lexical order, then the start scripts starting `S` are run in lexical order.  If you want to be sure everything is running use a start order of `99`.

Your distribution should have a method to install and remove links in the `rc#.d` directories.  In your case it appears to be `update-rc.d`.  This usually is controlled by comment lines at the top of the `init.d` script.

There should be `man` pages describing the programs and files you need.  Try running `man update-rc.d` and `man -k init`.

Answer (score 1):

Specify $network, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                          
### BEGIN INIT INFO                                                  
# Provides: mountftp                                                 
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog $network                        
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog $network                         
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5                                             
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6                                                
# Short-Description: Mount disk2                                     
# Description: Mount disk2                                           
### END INIT INFO
```